# /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1 in Xcode 6.4 (yosemite 10.10.5) when trying to run on iPad

Tags: provisioning-profile, provisioning, ios-provisioning

Everything started when I tried to create and validate my archive for the new app version.
My developer certificate expired, I revoked it (I didn't revoke distribution certificate it is still valid) and now it is up to date. I deleted my old associated provisioning profiled from Xcode and Xcode is configured to generate them automatically. After The provisioning profiles were not in my account.  I was able to compile fine without errors using simulator, but I can not run app on my iPad. I deleted old app version (I could not find in iPad Settings->General any Profiles to delete since my version is iOS8.4 and it deletes it automatically) I don't know if I need to delete anything else on iPad?
Now when I try to run from Xcode app on iPad, I get this error:
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
(see details below)
NOTE1: I don't get this error when I run it in the simulator, only when I chose to run on registered iPad
NOTE2: I was able to run app on this same iPad before I revoked the certificate.
NOTE3: I was able to create archive and submit the app before, problems started when certificates expired.
All troubles started after revoking the certificate.
I am running Xcode version 6.4
Mac has OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.5
Here is what I did so far:
After revoking certificates,I tried to delete provisioning profiles and restart Xcode, Mac and iPad and that didn't help.
I deleted old certificates from keychain, right now I have just the new up to date certificate in my keychain.
When I tried to run Xcode it asked me to fix non-existing provisioning profiles and it worked for simulator, but not for iPad.
I also looked in Xcode general settings for the build and tried various things, but that didn't help...
This didn't help too:
Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> Choose your account, and then View Details -> Refresh (button on bottom left), Refresh again, restart Xcode

I tried to read developer guides for distribution, but troubleshooting suggestions how to run on development device didn't help, also I didn't find much about this codsign error.
I also downloaded new certificate WWDR from Apple, that didn't help.
I tried most of the things what people suggested related to this error posted, but didn't help...
One additional info:
My problem is also that I am trying to submit second version of the existing app, so I don't know what I can delete in order to be able to submit the updated version  of my app again. If it was new project I would create new project from scratch and start from zero, but this happened just when I was ready to submit new archive...

Do you have any suggestion how to fix this issue, which steps to follow?
I would appreciate your pointers where to read or what to do.
If you need additional info from me, please let me know.
Thanking you in advance, -Tatjana

CodeSign /Users/t/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/K-eskcdowdkybtiygveputefcuziqr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/K.app
    cd /Users/t/Desktop/myProjects/K
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: T... (G....)"
Provisioning Profile: "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.k.K"
                      (5....)

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign D.... --entitlements /Users/t/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/K-e.../Build/Intermediates/K.build/Debug-iphoneos/K.build/K.app.xcent /Users/t/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/K-e..../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/K.app
```

CSSM_SignData returned: 8001094A
/Users/t/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/K-e..../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/K.app: errSecInternalComponent
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Comment: It sounds like you have a new certificate.  Do you have the private key for the certificate?  If you do, you should be able to expand the cert in Keychain Access and see a private key under it.  If you have that, have you regenerated the provisioning profile with the new certificate.  After generating a new cert, you also need to edit your profile to include the new cert.

Comment: Also, did you update your project build settings for your code signing identity to point to your new ios Developer certificate?

Comment: Yes, I do have private key for the new certificate. I do have under Build Settings in Xcode Provisioning Profile set to Automatic. I deleted all old provisioning profiles, and Xcode generates new ones automatically, I shouldn't need to edit them? Under Code Signing Identity I have Debug and Release set Any IOS SDK set to iOS Developer. Am I missing some other setting?

Comment: It doesn't seem like Xcode is generating a provisioning profile for you.  It's really easy to do through the Apple Dev site.  You go in, Create a new one, select the app ID, certificate, and devices you want to use, and click generate.  I have never had much luck letting Xcode do this stuff for me.  The "fix issues" button is so bad that Apple themselves made fun of it in their WWDC Developer State of the Union a couple of days ago.